# ASUS static route not working on RT-ACRH13

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, routing

### Configuration

I have an ASUS RT-ACRH13 router (latest firmware as I write this: 3.0.0.4.380_8228-g3af35f9) and DSL service (CenturyLink, PPPoE). The DSL modem is configured in "transparent bridge" mode (no NAT, PPPoE, etc.); the ASUS device is configured to connect with PPPoE and all of that works fine.

In order to reach the DSL modem's configuration page, I added a small NAT device ("router") in between the ASUS device and the DSL modem and configured a static route in the ASUS device to make the DSL modem's configuration page reachable. It looks like this:

```
     LAN                     LAN   WAN                   LAN
[ASUS]-------------------------[NAT]-----------------------[DSL]
     192.168.50.1   192.168.50.2   192.168.0.2   192.168.0.1
```

The static route in the ASUS device is as follows:

```
Network/Host IP   Netmask         Gateway        Metric   Interface
192.168.0.0       255.255.255.0   192.168.50.2   2        LAN
```

### Problem

From a device that is joined to the WiFi network, I **am able to ping 192.168.0.1**, but I **cannot telnet to 192.168.0.1 or go to http://192.168.0.1**. http and telnet fail when performed from a device on the WiFi network.

This same configuration (static route) **works without problems** from the WiFi network if I use an older Linksys router device.

### Question

Has anyone else run into any problems with static routes on an ASUS device? It seems odd that I can ping but not anything else--it's almost as if if ICMP works, but TCP does not.

Or have I discovered an obscure bug in the ASUS firmware?

### Update [2018/04/06]

I have narrowed down the scope of the problem. If my PPPoE connection is active, then the static route does **NOT** work. If I break the PPPoE connection (e.g., by entering invalid credentials), the static route **DOES** work.

I have delivered this information to ASUS technical support. Perhaps this can be resolved in a firmware update.

### Update [2018/05/07]

ASUS has not yet resolved this problem. I have worked around the problem for now by adding a static route on the computer. This workaround bypasses the routing in the ASUS device and works instantly. This further confirms my diagnosis that there is a bug in the ASUS firmware.

### Update [2018/05/20]

I can also work around this problem by assigning the DSL modem an IP address on the 192.168.50.0/24 network and connecting it to one of the LAN ports on the ASUS device. This also makes the DSL modem accessible from the wireless network. However the static routing problem remains.

Comment: I would really guess a software bug, as both networks are supposed to be bridged at layer2 and the distinction invisible to the IP layer. (Unless the networks got unbridged? Double-check your configuration.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this issue has been resolved with a newer firmware revision. I am now running firmware version **3.0.0.4.382_52243** -- I tried this configuration again, and now it works.